# How to perform shallow clone using Composer?

Tags: git, composer-php, shallow-clone

I've got the following `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.0",
        "queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "autoloader-suffix": "ComposerManager",
        "vendor-dir": "../../../all/libraries/composer"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP.git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I run:

```
$ composer -vvv update
...
Cloning master
Executing command (CWD): git clone --no-checkout 'https://github.com/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP.git' '.../sites/all/libraries/composer/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP' && cd '.../sites/all/libraries/composer/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP' && git remote add composer 'https://github.com/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP.git' && git fetch composer
```

the cloning process takes very long time and the repository grows over 25MB in size:

```
$ du -hs ~/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-queueit-KnownUser.V3.PHP.git/
25M ~/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-queueit-KnownUser.V3.PHP.git/
```

Then the Composer stops with the timeout:

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
>       The process "`git clone --no-checkout 'https://github.com/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP.git' '.../sites/all/libraries/composer/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP' && cd '.../sites/all/libraries/composer/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP' && git remote add composer 'https://github.com/queueit/KnownUser.V3.PHP.git' && git fetch composer`" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

I assume the repository is too big to clone all the git objects.

---

How I can clone the repository quicker by using [a shallow clone](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt)?

For example by passing extra `--depth 1` or `--single-branch` git parameters into Git command, so it can be automatically picked up by Composer?

I expect the change to be self-contained within the `composer.json` file, so no external configuration should be required when invoked this file on the other systems or by other users when running `composer install`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shallow cloning using *Composer* isn't officially supported (without any patching) as the *git* parameters are hardcoded.

There is already a feature request to add this: [Add support for git shallow clones](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3449). However implementing this feature can cause some issues (such as not reaching the locked commits if the depth is not so high<sup>[@stof](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3449#issuecomment-63966102)</sup> and other).

Furthermore there is a [pull request](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/4961) which attempts to implement shallow clones by adding an extra `--git-clone-depth` parameter (tests shows some good results). However the change has been abandon due to [faster git clones using cache](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5384).

---

For the quick hack, it's possible to edit git parameters in `doDownload()` in `src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php`, e.g. by changing `--depth 1 --single-branch` in this line:

```
$command = 'git clone --no-checkout ...'
```

Or find the way to apply depth 1 setting into git config.

---

The easiest workaround (without any hacks) for bigger repositories is just to increase the timeout by specifying the variable like:

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=0 composer install
```